# cancel button using php

Tags: php

I have a form,if users clicks cancel with value or w/o value in the textfield it should redirect.

Now w/o entering value it is working.If users enters it is getting into db.

I tried all js scripts but still not working

http://pastebin.com/qYLVrMC7

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Why redirec? Should cancel work as canceling the actual action and getting back to previous one? I thing that history.back() should be suffcient in js. Or window.close() if the form is opened in new window.
But to make this happend you should make cancel a regular button, not a submit.

Something like this:`<input type="button" ... value="Cancel" onclick="history.back();" />`

Comment: thanks macino - I must have voted this up a while back and forgot.  Just found it again, and attempted to vote it up again.  simple, clean, elegant

Answer (score 3):

Try this and change redirectpage to your redirectpage.

`<input type="button" value="cancel" onClick="document.location.href='http://www.redirectpage.com';" />`

Comment: <input name="button3" type="submit" class="button" id="button" value="Cancel"  />
value uses a uppercase C and when you check you are checking for lowercase c + the if statement have been made a comment dus not executed
 
/*if ($_POST['cancel'] == 'submit')

Answer (score 2):

whenever you have an `<input type="submit">` think of this as just another field value you can check against in your code. e.g. try this:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="GET">
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="submit">
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="cancel">
</form> 

<?php 
//validation removed..

if ($_GET['foo'] == 'submit')
{

//do snazzy stuff
print('submit pressed')

}

if ($_GET['foo']) == 'cancel')
{

//do snazzy stuff
print('cancel pressed')



}


?>
```

hope this helps?

Answer (score 1):

You should emphasize the default (submit) action versus the secondary one (cancel). Make submit a regular submit button, cancel a link to the previous page.