# Why I need to use history.back(); twice for cancel button

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter-3

I created a cancel button using the method explained by macino in this thread
[cancel button using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553714/cancel-button-using-php)

But I have to use history.back(); twice to cancel the form. What is the reason for that? Thanks.

```
$post_counter=1;
      foreach ($comment as $c) {
        echo $c['comment'] . "<br>";
        echo "By " . $c['first_name'] . "<br>";
        if($c['uid'] == $current_user) { ?>
          <a href="<?php echo "#post_edit_link" . $post_counter; ?>" id="<?php echo "post_edit_link" . $post_counter; ?>" onclick="show_postedit_box(this.id);">Edit</a><br>
          <div id="<?php echo "post_edit_box" . $post_counter; ?>" style="display:none">
              <form id="<?php echo "reply_form" . $post_counter; ?>" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('Forum/update_comment'); ?>">
                  <input type="text" name="edit_comment" value="<?php echo $c['comment'];?>" class="form-control">
                  <input type='hidden' name='edit_cid' value='<?php echo $c['id']; ?>'/>
                  <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
                  <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="history.back();history.back();" />
              </form>
           </div>
          <script>
              function show_postedit_box(clicked_edit_id){
                let str_edit = clicked_edit_id;
                str_edit.replace("post_edit_link", "");
                //console.log('mylink' + str.replace("mylink", ""));
                document.getElementById('post_edit_box' + str_edit.replace("post_edit_link", "")).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById('post_edit_link' + str_edit.replace("post_edit_link", "")).style.display = "none";
              }
          </script>
        <?php
          $post_counter++;
        }
```

Comment: Double action, submit form and history go back.